# Firebase/AngularFire performance issues causing page to become unresponsive? $watch at fault?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've built a site with angularfire and I've noticed that as the site is left open it begins to lag and eventually freezes the browser.

Is there a way I can trace this to the source to see what's causing it?

It's very likely this double watch function but I can't seem to get the list to sort properly and repopulate when I change .start() and .end() parameters on my $firebase array.

```
  scope.$watch(function(){
    scope.list.$watch(updateList);
    return scope.list;
  }, updateList);
```

Seems to be related to the nesting. The following works much better. Can anyone please explain why I need to have two $watches setup?

```
  scope.list.$watch(updateList);
  scope.$watch(function(scope){
    return scope.list;
  }, updateList);
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, this code will recursively establish listeners, increasing the resource usage each time there is a change in scope.

It's unclear why you've chosen to watch both scope and the list's $watch method, but only one of these should be necessary.

```
list.$watch(function() {
   // do whatever needs to be done when the list changes
});
```

Also, updateList implies that you're changing the list or making copies of it. If you are changing the list inside a $watch event, that's going to trigger more watch events. If you're making copies of the list, those are probably unnecessary.

More context about the use case and end goal could help with specifics.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding how to use $watch. The correct syntax would be.

```
scope.$watch('list', updateList);
```

Alternatively,

```
scope.$watch('list', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if (someConditional) {
         updateList()
     }
});
```

See for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: The original poster is asking about $watch function within the context of firebase/angularfire